# FatalThrowableError in Connection.php line 149: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 with mongodb.
firstly I have created the laravel project using the command

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel NC_Data`

Then I have install the latest version of the mongodb package using the composer like:

`composer require jenssegers/mongodb`

Added the below line in config/app.php, in providers array:

`Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class`

and in the aliases array:

`'Moloquent' => 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model'`

below is the  connections array in app/config/database.php, :

```
'mongodb' => array(
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'options' => array(
    'db' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by 
       mongo 3)
),
```

Also changed the default DB_Connection:

`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),`

When I run my project using CLI command of laravel i.e php artisan serve.It will run on port 8000 i.e http://localhost:8000/listing it works perfectly.But When try to run it using http://localhost/NC_Data/listing. NC_Data is my project folder,it gives me the below error:

FatalThrowableError in Connection.php line 149:
Class 'MongoClient' not found.

Can anybody please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you actually create your project? You should have done a `larvel new` and various other stages. These things covered in various existing tutorials make sure you install all required dependencies. The message indicates you are missing something, so if you are asking a question then you should list all your steps to create your project you have taken so far.

Comment: I have followed the steps which are there in the laravel doc for creating new project, here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation

Comment: So a "question" posted here requires you to actually "show what you did within your question". Saying things like "I did all the steps" does not show people what you actually did. Writing all the steps within your question does.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question with the steps that I have followed